# Taylor approximation of theory of relativity

Tags: taylor-expansion

I don't understand part two of the following question:

a) Let $x\in[0;1)$. Prove by using Taylor series that $(1-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3}{8}(1-\xi)^{-\frac{5}{2}}x^2$.

This was straight forward. I calculated the Taylor series to the first degree to the point $a=0$:

$P_{1,a=0}(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)=1+\frac{x}{2}$

Afterwards I calculated the remainder:

$$R_{1,a=0}(x)=\frac{f''(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}=\frac{3x^2}{8(1-\xi)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

Adding these two together, I get:

$$(1-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=P_{1,a=0}(x)+R_{1,a=0}(x)=1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3x^2}{8(1-\xi)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

---

The second part is:

b) According to Einstein, a particle's kinetic energy is given by:

$$E_{kin}(v)=m_0c^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{v}{c})^2}}-1\right), 0≤v<c$$

Where $m_0$ is the invariant mass, $c$ is speed of light $(3*10^5\frac{km}{s})$ and v is the velocity of the particle.

The classic kinetic energy is defined as:

$$T(v)=\frac{1}{2}m_0v^2$$

The relative error made by replacing $E_{kin}(v)$ with $T(v)$ can be calculated by:

$$E=\frac{E_{kin}(v)-T(v)}{E_{kin}(v)}$$

Show by using the approximating polynomial from the point $a=0$ out of $(1-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ that

$$E<\frac{3(\frac{v}{c})^2}{4(1-(\frac{v}{c})^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

I feel completely lost on this part. I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply the Taylor expansion with $x=(v/c)^2$ (this you probably guessed?). There is  a small catch as you divide by $E_{\rm kin}$ so you also need to produce a *lower* bound for that. This is, however, not difficult as you may use the very same Taylor expansion and note that the last correction term is positive, so $(1-x)^{-\frac12}-1\geq \frac{x}{2} $.

Comment: Haha, this is where I got tricked, too: the problem asks for an *upper* bound for $E$; by obtaining a *lower* bound for $E_{kin}$ you get an *upper* bound for $\dfrac 1 {E_{kin}}$, therefore a *lower* bound for $-\dfrac 1 {E_{kin}}$, therefore a *lower* bound for $E = 1 - \frac T {E_{kin}}$ - precisely the opposite of what is required!

Comment: No, you have to rethink. The kinetic energy is positive and so is E.

Comment: Assuming that I correctly understand your idea (which I might not), since you discard the term $(1 - \xi) ^{- \frac 5 2}$ in order to obtain your lower bound, how could one obtain $\left( 1 - \frac {v^2} {c^2} \right) ^{\frac 5 2}$ in the denominator of the final formula? The discarded term was the only one capable of producing such a power.

Comment: That term is kept in the numerator (Ekin-T) in an upper bound but is discarded in the denominator (Ekin) in a lower bound.